# React native app crashes after build successful

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

My app crashes after build without any error. Later after debugging, I found the below error in logcat of Android Studio. How to solve this.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
    Process: com.myapp, PID: 11305
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libfolly_json.so" not found: needed by /data/app/~~4gp2E7YtL8o-49YMQ4uIrQ==/com.myapp-7jUAREIQl67FHrb4so-s0Q==/lib/arm64/libreanimated.so in namespace classloader-namespace
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1077)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:998)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1656)
        at com.swmansion.reanimated.NativeProxy.<clinit>(NativeProxy.java:26)
        at com.swmansion.reanimated.NodesManager.initWithContext(NodesManager.java:140)
        at com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedJSIModulePackage.getJSIModules(ReanimatedJSIModulePackage.java:24)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1389)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1200(ReactInstanceManager.java:136)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:1108)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11305 SIG: 9
```

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: hello, did you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have reanimated library installed.
just install

```
npm i react-native-reanimated
```

then sync gradle and try to run app.